# Broadcom BCM4313 wireless slow and high-latency

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Install Broadcom / STA Wireless card (BCM43XX)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-sta-wireless-card-bcm43xx)

Ubuntu 12.10 64 bit on a Dell Latitude E6330 laptop.

Wireless is pretty slow. It gets connected quick enough, but then it acts like a dialup connection. My ssh sessions over WiFi are slow and laggy. Even browsing is slow, the pages are loading like it's 1998.

This does not depend on the access point, it's the same both at home and at work. Other systems work fine on these access points.

I had an older Dell laptop before, different WiFi hardware, and it was much faster over the same wireless access points.

Is this a known issue with this hardware? If so, any solutions?